# jQueryUI Draggable - grid and containment options

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable

The problem is this : When set the **grid** and the **containment** options there is a problem on the drag event.
Some object (according to their starting position) can't approach completely to the edges of the container. There is a way to solve this problem? (without changing the event drag?)

[image]

### html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="obj1"></div>
    <div id="obj2"></div>
</div>
```

### js

```
$("#obj1,#obj2").draggable({
    containment : "parent",
    grid : [3,3]
});
```

### css

```
#container{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#obj1{
    position:absolute;
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    background:blue;
    left:27px;
    top:27px;
}
#obj2{
    position:absolute;
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    background:red;
    left:53px;
    top:103px;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whiteline/9oLtt9uy/1/)
(obj1 is ok , obj2 (in this case) isn't ok)

Comment: you mean the red object to the left of the container ?

Comment: yes , obj blue is ok , obj red isn't ok

Answer (score 1):

You have set the grid to [3, 3] which means jQuery will increment/decrement the position of the objects with 3 pixels either way. So you need to align the starting position on the grid if you want the object to be able to reach [0, 0]:

```
#obj2{
    position:absolute;
    width:53px;
    height:53px;
    background:red;
    left:54px;
    top:105px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9oLtt9uy/2/

**Update**

If your starting coordinates are variable, you should dynamically adjust them, so they are aligned, for example:

```
var gridSpacing = 10,
    gridSize = $("#obj1").width();

// make sure the grid is big enough to fit an exact number of objects
$("#container").width(gridSpacing * gridSize + 2);
$("#container").height(gridSpacing * gridSize + 2);

// align each object and make it draggable    
$("#obj1,#obj2").each(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "left": ($(this).position().left - ($(this).position().left % gridSpacing) - 1),
        "top": ($(this).position().top - ($(this).position().top % gridSpacing) - 1)
    });

    $(this).draggable({
        containment : "parent",
        grid : [gridSpacing,gridSpacing]
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/9oLtt9uy/6/

Comment: yeah, this is the case :)

Comment: Yes, I know , but this is normal .. Otherwise I would not have asked the question . I need to allow users to move objects in a grid ( for example 3-3 but is just an example ) ,  but if the object is approaching the edges , must be able to still "stick" to the edges (whatever the type of grid)

Comment: But that is not the question you asked. What do you mean exactly by "stick" to the edges? Reach or stick? Please update the question.

Comment: yes it's. but I can't set to 0-0 the initial position of the objects that i have to move , because the initial position of the objects is taken from a database (and thus the initial position must be the last position of the object )

Comment: One solution would be to turn off the grid when the object have a particular x-y

Comment: no, it can be a solution . because in this case the position of the object is modified , and therefore fails to comply what i said in the previous comments . I will use my solution , thanks anyway :)